# Insert a line after match using sed

Tags: sed

I want to insert a new line after this line:

```
set_config_object("m_lin_1_pad_agent*","io_agent_config",m_lin_1_pad_agent_cfg,0);
```

Can you please guide me on how I can achieve that using the `sed` command?

Comment: I think this should answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559359/insert-line-after-first-match-using-sed/25306308

Answer (score 1):

[Brian Z's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261767/insert-a-line-after-match-using-sed#comment2133448_1261767) is a good suggestion. Indeed, using the `a` command in `sed` will append a string after the match.

However, if you directly use the string in your question as the matching string, you will find that nothing will happen. The problem is the `*` character inside your string, which should be escaped, since `sed` uses this character for regex match. In `sed` you can escape a character by using a backslash (`\`)  in front of it. You can find some more info about the characters that should be escaped in this [U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script).

So, the `sed` command you need to run in order to append a string `newstring` in a file called `file.txt` after matching your string is (notice the escaped `*`):

```
sed -i -e '/set_config_object("m_lin_1_pad_agent\*","io_agent_config",m_lin_1_pad_agent_cfg,0);/ a newstring' file.txt
```

In the above command `-i` is used to change the file in place. If you want to preview the changes first and ensure that the command works as it should, run the command without the `-i` flag.

Comment: Pedantically, `a` is not a flag, it is a command. The `/pattern/` specifies the *address* for the `a` command.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks! Changed that.